# JavaScript Add Textbox Dynamically when Button onClick

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add a new textbox when add button is onclick using JavaScript. Here is my HTML:

```
htmlStr += "<div id='filterContent' style='width:100%;text-align:center;'>";
htmlStr += "<input id='startLoc' type='text' />";
htmlStr += "<input id='endLoc' type='text' />";
htmlStr += "<input id='addLoc' type='button' value='Add' onClick='addTextBox()' />";
htmlStr += "</div><br/>";
```

And here is my JavaScript to add a new textbox when button is onClick:

```
function addTextBox(){
var element = document.createElement("input");

element.setAttribute("type", "text");
element.setAttribute("value", "");
element.setAttribute("name", "Test Name");
//element.setAttribute("style", "width:200px");

var foo = document.getElementById("filterContent");
foo.appendChild(element);
}
```

It works perfectly to add as many textbox as I want. But somehow the textbox created share the same id. I wonder is that possible to add many textbox with different ID each time when the button is onClick?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your current setup you could keep track of an id increment in a global:

```
//outside function
var idIndex = 1;

function addTextBox(){
var element = document.createElement("input");

element.setAttribute("type", "text");
element.setAttribute("value", "");
element.setAttribute("name", "Test Name");
element.setAttribute("id", "addLoc" + idIndex++);
element.setAttribute("style", "width:200px");

element.onclick = function()
{
    //do something
 }


var foo = document.getElementById("filterContent");
foo.appendChild(element);
}
```

**EDIT:** To answer the question in this answer's comments. It is certainly possible to add a different onclick handler for every new textbox (although you're probably better off designing your handlers so you can use a single handler for **all** but if you wanted for some reason to use a different one you could bind an anonymous function to the handler, I have added an approach above).

**EDIT2:** Regarding the second question in the path there are two approaches you could use. Instead of calling the separate functions `getFirstPath()` `getSecondPath()` etc. individually, you could have a single function called `getPath()` and pass the index to it as a parameter:

```
var getPath = function(index) {

    switch(index)
    {
        case 1:
            return getFirstPath();
            break;
        case 2:
            return getSecondPath();
            break; //and so on.
    }
}
```

And then your `onclick` would look like this:

```
element.onclick = function()
{
    getPath(index);
}
```

Comment: Also, I wonder everytime when I created a new textbox, is that possible to set different onClick event to them? For example, I added textbox3 which will fire function3. And texbox4 fires function4 and so on.

Comment: Okay sure, thanks a lot. But one last question, I wanted to append the textbox to a new line everytime when the add button is onClick. I tried this approach: foo.appendChild("<br/>" + element); but it threw me an error message: Uncaught NotFoundError: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.

Comment: Also, sorry for keep asking questions. Can you please elaborate what am I supposed to do inside the onClick. Let's say addLoc1 will execute getFirstPath(). then addLoc2 will execute getSecondPath(). How should I add it in. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're getting an error because `<br/>` is an element. You would need to do something like `var lbreak = document.createElement("br"); foo.appendChild(element); foo.appendChild(lbreak);`

Comment: Regarding your second question, there are a number of ways, you could redesign the `getPath` function to be less coupled to the path or if thats not an option, you might have to map those functions into an array and then reference the function based on the `idIndex` I'll put an example into my answer above

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works! Thanks for spending your time to help me :)

Answer (score 3):

```
var aa=Math.random();   
 <input id='addLoc"+aa+"' type='text' />
```

User [**math.random**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) to generate random id's for a textbox

Comment: +1 this is a great approach and doesn't rely on globals like mine, globals **can** be bad news (although I am a heretic and disagree that they are bad news in EVERY project).